# Redirecting referrer URLs based on new site structure

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I'm trying to redirect incoming connections based on the referrer URL.  So for instance if someone was trying to visit:

```
blog.example.com/category/fancy-stuff
```

They are already getting redirected to example.com but I want to redirect them to:

```
example.com/news/category/fancy-stuff
```

Right now I have this for my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERRER} blog.example.com/category/* [NC] 

RewriteRule ^ example.com/news/category/*? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to use variables or something to just append the proper category to the new URL?

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your Rewrite rules :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERRER} ^blog.example.com/category/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/news/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```